# django testing: How to start a background process that can access the test database?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I'm trying to write a test using the django testing framework, the test spawns a new background process that has access the test datebase. The test looks like this,

*temp_project/temp_app/tests.py*

```
import subprocess
from django.test import TestCase                                                                                                                    
from temp_app.models import TempModel

# Create your tests here.                                                                                                                             

class TempTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        TempModel.objects.create()

    def test_main(self):

        self.assertEqual(str(TempModel.objects.all()) + '\n',
                     subprocess.check_output(['python', 'manage.py', 'temp_command']))
```

The subprocess simply prints out the contents of the database, *temp_project/temp_app/management/commands/temp_command.py*

```
from temp_app.models import TempModel
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print TempModel.objects.all()
```

The model is an empty placeholder, *temp_project/temp_app/models.py*

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.                                                                                                                            
class TempModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

However the output from the test looks like,

```
> python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_main (temp_app.tests.TempTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dvoong/projects/opentrv/ors/source/temp/temp_project/temp_app/tests.py", line 15, in test_main
    subprocess.check_output(['python', 'manage.py', 'temp_command']))
AssertionError: '[<TempModel: TempModel object>]\n' != '[]\n'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.285s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

So it seems the subprocess is accessing the production database instead of the test one. Any ideas? The database settings are, the default values,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess not using the test database is to be expected since you the subprocess isn't running a test command anyway. The solution would be to create a new settings file and pass it as a parameter to your subprocess using the `--settings` parameter. Naturally this new settings file should point to the test database.